# How do I combine YEAR and MONTH into a DATE?

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm looking for an easier way to do this.  My current code is written as below:

```
CASE WHEN LENGTH(CAST (MTH AS VARCHAR(4))) = 1 
     THEN CAST(CAST (YR AS VARCHAR(4))||'-0'||CAST (MTH AS VARCHAR(4))||'-01' AS DATE)
     ELSE CAST(CAST (YR AS VARCHAR(4))||'-' ||CAST (MTH AS VARCHAR(4))||'-01' AS DATE)
END AS RPT_MTH
```

The table has a field called YR with the 4 digit Year.  MTH field is just a number 1 through 12, with no leading 0 for 1-9.

Is there an easier way to get to the RPT_MTH than what I'm currently doing?

Answer (score 2):

Based on Teradata's internal date:

```
cast((yr-1900) * 10000 + mth * 100 + 1 as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little shorter:

```sql
cast(cast(YR*10000+MTH*100+1 as char(8)) as date format 'YYYYMMDD') AS RPT_MTH
```

Or if you need to stick to character operations:

```sql
cast(cast(YR as char(4))||right('0'||cast(MTH as varchar(2)),2) as date format 'YYYYMM')
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**`CONCAT`**](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-SQL-Functions-Expressions-and-Predicates/March-2019/String-Operators-and-Functions/CONCAT/Argument-Type-and-Rules), [**`LPAD`**](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/e5w8LujIQDlVmRSww2E27A), [**`TO_CHAR`**](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/4xbLyOA_385QLYctkj%7Ehjw) and [**`TO_DATE`**](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/UA9LRMzyH1zxZhsWKDoGPA) which may vary in support depending on your version. Default format for `TO_DATE` is ISO date format at: `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

```
TO_DATE(CONCAT(YR, '-', LPAD(TO_CHAR(MTH), 2, '0'), '-01'))
```